# Debug VC++ app in command line

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-c++

Is it possible to debug a vc++ application in command line? I mean, is there any windows dos debugging tool like gdb that I can use to debug a vc++ application in command line (DOS)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the .NET Framework Command-Line Debugger? If you have the Visual Studio IDE installed, open the command prompt from the VS Tools, and you're good to go.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861.aspx

And another option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx

Comment: I don't see how a .NET Framework debugger is going to be very useful for a C++ application.